# Connection refused to localhost with Spring Rest-Template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I want to use spring rest-template to connect to a rest-service. The application looks more or less like the example here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

But even when I try to connect to a service on localhost I get an I/O Error Connection Refused. With a plain curl call to the same URL there is no problem. What can this be?

Comment: Show some of your code, and the curl equivalent you're using.

Comment: You can take the example from the above link. Just substitute the url to a service on localhost. Then I get a Connection Refused, on MacOS.

Comment: There is no problem if I use the apache HttpClient. The URL is exactly the same.